# Spotfire - Create a KPI based on a Calculated column condition

Tags: spotfire, tibco, spotfire-analyst

I have a table like so:

```
          Project           Task                  Completion     

           P1              Scheduling             20/01/2021

           P1              Filing                 19/01/2021  

           P2              Admin                     

           P2              Safety                 19/01/2021
```

In this table Project P1 is complete, as both tasks have completion dates. P2 is not complete as only one task has a completion date. I want to create a KPI that shows the number of completed projects, which in this case would be 1. ie. Show the number of projects with 100% completion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see my answer on TIBCO Community

https://community.tibco.com/questions/i-want-create-kpi-based-calculated-column-condition

Calculate column [Incomplete] as:

case  when [Completion] is null then [Project] end

The value of KPI is:

UniqueCount([Project]) - UniqueCount([Incomplete])

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28170446)

Comment: I edited it, but even before, it did not mean the answer was not useful so why down vote it? And also why vote to delete it?